# how to invoke a Property of a null reference object

Tags: c#, data-structures

Consider the following class which contains a property Height

```
internal class TreeNode
{
  public int value;
  public TreeNode Left;
  public TreeNode Right;

  public int Height{get;private set}
}
```

a `TreeNode` type variable `node` is initialized (i.e `node==null` returns false) and `TreeNode.Left =null`

Trying `node.Left.Height` will throw a NullRefrenceException, Is there any direct way so that i can access the property Height from a null reference object so that `node.Left.Height` returns -1.

I know one method is to use a function with a signature `int getHeight(TreeNode node)` where i can check the node for nullity. but i want to use `node.Left.Height` kind of expression to return the desired value.

Comment: I'd recommend changing your logic to handle null. And then use the null propogation operator to prevent the Null Reference Exception.

Comment: @JeffSiver same thoughts exactly

Comment: I don´t understand your question, if a member is null it means there is *is* none set, thus there´s no instance to which a `Height` could belong. Itßs like asking for asking the hight of a house that doesn´t exist.

Comment: @HimBromBeere exactly, asking a Height of a house that doesn't exists is a valid question, and it's answer will be 0.

Comment: No, it´s not a valid question, there is simply no height as there´s no building. Anyway even if this would make any sense it´s not possible in OOP, as every property (`Height` in our case) belongs to to instances of classes, in our case a `Building`. No building-->no height (not even zero height, just none at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people have made similar suggestions, but you could do something like

```
text?.Length ?? -1
```

If text is null it'll give the default value -1. There is no way to "directly" do text.Length though - that wouldn't make sense because there is no object to get the length *of*.

As an analogy, if I were to ask you what the height of the unicorn living in Milwaukee, WI is, how would you answer? Clearly, there *is* no unicorn in Milwaukee, WI to get the height of, so there's no way to give a meaningful answer other than "there is no such unicorn."

Comment: this is working perfectly, and this is the best way! thanks to null propagation and null coalescing operators!

Comment: @Sherlock not ignored man! but his answer is more descriptive for the above problem  ;)

Answer (score 4):

You're asking how to get the height of an undefined object? That is simply not possible. Like you can't measure the height of an building if it is not there.

Stick to the method based approach. Or create a property in your class like this:

```
public int LeftHeight 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return Left == null ? -1 : Left.Height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement properties for Left and Right that never return null.

```
private TreeNode _left;
private TreeNode _right;
public TreeNode Left
{
    get
    {
        return _left ?? new TreeNode() { Height = -1 };
    }
    set
    {
        _left = value;
    }
}
public TreeNode Right
{
    get
    {
        return _right ?? new TreeNode() { Height = -1 };
    }
    set
    {
        _right = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: But now you can legally do `tn.Left.value = 911;` when there is no `TreeNode` assigned to `Left`...and that value will simply "disappear".  That'll be a good bug/feature to troubleshoot down the line...  =/

Comment: Technically, Height has a private setter, but I get your point.

Comment: We're not setting `Height`, we're setting `value`.

Comment: @JohnKoerner i think it might create problem while adding a node recursively. because accessing left or right will never return null.
but i think i can use it like this
`root.(left??new TreeNode() {Height = -1}).Height `

Answer (score 0):

Actually when u are dealing with c# 6 there is a null propagation operator.

Sample:

`int? length = text?.Length;`

[Null Propagation OPerator](https://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/)

Comment: You can't do it. If `text` is `null` then your expression will return null, but you can't assign `null` to `int`.

Comment: @Roma you can do it now in C# 6.0. It will prevent from throwing exceptions

Comment: You haven't tested it but you say that it works. See http://prntscr.com/dyiuqo. `Height` property type is `int`

Comment: Well this won't work for reasons @Roma told you. the operator will return null when the source is null so you will need a nullable int. And that is what OP odes not want.

Comment: This will return null if text is null - it should be -1 in this case, so this doesn't really do what the OP is asking for.